# AWK, exclude results from one file with regards to a second file

Tags: awk

Using Awk, I am able to get a list of URL with a given error number :

```
awk '($9 ~ /404/)' /var/log/nginx/access.log | awk '{print $7}' | sort | uniq -c | sort -rn
```

Fine and dandy.

But we would like to further refine it by matching that result against a list of already know 404 URL

example :

```
awk '($9 ~ /404/)' /var/log/nginx/access.log | awk '{print  $7} '| sort | uniq -c | sort -k 2 -r |  awk '{print > "/mnt/tmp/404error.txt"}'
```

yield today :

```
1 /going-out/restaurants/the-current-restaurent.htm
1 /going-out/restaurants/mare.HTML
1 /going-out/report-content/?cid=5
1 /going-out/report-content/?cid=38550
1 /going-out/report-content/?cid=380
```

the day after :

```
1 /going-out/ru/%d0%bd%d0%be%d1%87%d0%bd%d0%b0%d1%8f-%d0%b6%d0%b8%d0%b7%d0%bd%d1%8c-%d0%bd%d0%b0-%d0%bf%d1%85%d1%83%d0%ba%d0%b5%d1%82%d0%b5/%d1%81%d0%be%d0%b2%d0%b5%d1%82%d1%8b-%d0%bb%d1%8e%d0%b1%d0%b8%d1%82%d0%b5%d0%bb%d1%8f%d0%bc-%d0%bd%d0%be%d1%87%d0%bd%d1%8b%d1%85-%d1%80%d0%b0%d0%b7%d0%b2%d0%bb%d0%b5%d1%87%d0%b5%d0%bd%d0%b8%d0%b9/
1 /going-out/restaurants/the-current-restaurent.htm
1 /going-out/restaurants/mare.HTML
1 /going-out/report-content/?cid=5
1 /going-out/report-content/?cid=38550
1 /going-out/report-content/?cid=380
1 /going-out/report-content/?cid=29968
1 /going-out/report-content/?cid=29823
```

The goal is to have only the new URL.

At that point I am lost, I know I can push first file into an array, I presume I can do the same with the second file (but in a second array), then maybe (not sure if awk does have the capacity) simply cross them, and kept what does not match.

Any help will be fully appreciate.

Comment: So you have an existing file with urls that were matched and you want to print those that match the condition but are not in that file?

Comment: More or less. I have a file with URL/path that we already checked, and every week I get from access.log a new list of 404. I want to cross them, and have print the list of those that are not in the first (mean new 404). I am french so it is hard for me to explain, reason why my question was so verbous.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

So you have a file whose `$9` field may match `/404/`. If so, you want to store the 7th field. Then, count how many of them appeared in total, but just if they did not appear before in a file you have.

I think all of this can be done with this (untested, because I have no sample input data):

```
awk 'FNR==NR {seen[$2];next}
     $9 ~ /404/ {if !($7 in seen) a[$7]++}
     END {for (i in a) print a[i], i}' old_file log_file
```

This stores the 2nd column from the file with data into an array `seen[]`. Then, goes through the new file and stores the 7th column if it wasn't seen before. Finally, it prints the counters.

---

Since it looks like you have an old `awk` version that does not support the syntax `index in array`, you can use this workaround for it:

```
$9 ~ /404/ {for (i in seen) {if (i==$7) next} a[$7]++}
```

Note you must be using a veeery old version, since this was introduced in 1987:

> [**A.1 Major Changes Between V7 and SVR3.1**](http://www.gnu.org/software/gawk/manual/gawk.html#V7_002fSVR3_002e1)
>
> The awk language evolved considerably between the release of Version 7
>   Unix (1978) and the new version that was first made generally
>   available in System V Release 3.1 (1987). This section summarizes the
>   changes, with cross-references to further details:
>
> The expression ‘indx in array’ outside of for statements (see
>   Reference to Elements)

Comment: Thanks, I will test tha t within 24 hours. I am not sure it is exactly what I need; but it seems to me it does have all the info I needed to start. Thanks for it, back here within 24 hours.

Comment: Precission, sample datas are in the question: "yield today :" is followed by 5 lines (the file does have 885 similar lines) ; "the day after :" is followed by 8 lines (the file may have 2 000 for example). the column #0 is the total time the path appear in the log, column #1 is the path.

Comment: awk:                                        ^ syntax error

Comment: @Sting01 what version of awk are you using? Try to update your original post showing a [mcve].

Comment: Fedorqui, did you read the question? Or is it my english is that bad you simply did not understood (possible, I am french, my english sucks). you samples, you have the code.

Comment: Anyway, I did find a solution, buy amending your proposal. While I do not master awk, I do have 40 years expeerience in coding, so my code is ugly but fuonctional.

Comment: Concept is : I have file with PHYSICAL PATH of file that return 404 (the very fist day there is nothing but one character), I check the access.log, Every 404 are add to that file, and those that were not into it already (new 404) are printed into another file, that I eventually send by email. The day after, wash, rince ,repeat. Specificity such as amouont of column in file 1 are irrelevant, because it will be the amount of columns I will print at the end.

Comment: Anyway, I THANK you, without your example (even with the error) I would not have finish that in a realistic amount of time. Now  I must improve it.

Comment: @Sting01 you are welcome : ) I have the feeling that you are using an old awk, because of the problem on the `($7 in seen)`. If you for example are in Solaris, use `/usr/xpg4/bin/awk` instead.

Comment: Ubuntu 12.xx; I am quite confident you nailed the problem, but one of my specs ( I know, because I am the one who wrote it) is to have some backward compatibilities. It does not change the validity ofyour response, it only mean it can not apply in my very specific case.

Comment: @Sting01 updated with a workaround for the `index in array` syntax. Let us know if it worked!

Answer (score 0):

You can use `grep --fixed-strings --file=FILEALL FILENEW` or `comm -23 FILENEW FILEALL` for this. FILEALL is the file containing the urls already found, FILENEW contains the pages found today. For `comm` both files must be sorted.

http://www.gnu.org/software/gawk/manual/gawk.html#Other-Inherited-Files

http://linux.die.net/man/1/comm

I think `comm`is more efficient because I uses sorted files, but I did not test this.

Answer (score 0):

I came up with the following :

```
awk 'BEGIN {
while (getline < "/mnt/tmp/404error.txt") {
A[$1] = $1;
};

while (getline < "/var/log/nginx/access.log") {
if( $9 ~ /404/) 
{
{
exist[$7] = $7 ;
}
{
if ($7 in A) blah += 1; else new[$7];
}
}
}
{
asort(exist);
for(i in exist)
print exist[i] > "/mnt/tmp/404error.txt"
}
{
asorti(new);
for(i in new)
print new[i] > "/mnt/tmp/new404error.txt"
}
}
' | mutt -s "subject" -a /mnt/tmp/new404error.txt -- whoever@mail.net, whatever@mail.net
```

that seems providing me what I want (almost).

But I believe it is verbous too much, might be possible one of you genius can improve it 
Thanks